# Swing : Screen components doesn't get refreshed as expected

Tags: java, swing, components, refresh, repaint

I have a middlePanel that displays panel1 with 6 button in it. On clicking a button, other components are displayed in mainPanel and finally returning back to panel1.

The problem I face here is : the components aren't shown at once - I got go move cursor around to make it visible. The code I use to set the panels is :

```
public void SetMainPanel(JPanel panel) {
    middlePanel.removeAll();
    this.middlePanel = panel;
    panel.setVisible(true);
    this.middlePanel.setVisible(true);
    mainPanel.add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    middlePanel.revalidate();
    middlePanel.repaint();
    mainPanel.revalidate();
    mainPanel.repaint();
}
```

See am set visible to the passed panel, and middlePanel in which it is added. updateui & validate middlePanel and mainPanel that contains middlePanel. Yet why is this problem.

Can anyone help me know why is this problem and how o solve it. I feel their is a way to get rid of this problem but couldn't recall it.

Comment: Many calls to `validate()`, `updateUI()`? Why don't just use `repaint()`?

Comment: @eee, It's also necessary to have the layout manager layout it's components again, which `repaint()` doesn't do.

Comment: do you call this method in the Event dispatch thread?

Comment: @josefx, I call this method from other Panel class and pass its instance to this method to set it as the middlePanel. I call it normally : myParent.SetMainPanel(new DataPanel(this));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988317/dynamically-add-components-to-a-jdialog/6988341#6988341) I gave someone else when asked about dynamically adding/removing components:

> When dynamically adding/removing components from a container, it's
>   necessary to invoke revalidate()/validate() and repaint() afterward.
>   The former will force the container to layout its components again and
>   the latter will remove any visual "artifacts".

And by the way, in this scenario, it's completely unnecessary to invoke `updateUI()`. And as a suggestion, perhaps using a different layout manager (e.g. [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)) would serve you better.

Comment: +1, for revalidate and for noting updateUI is completely unnecessary. Also, whenever I see the removeAll() method I would also recommend the CardLayout.

Comment: @mre, eee, dk89, as you experts suggested, I commented updateUI() and added mainPanel.repaint() in the last. That didn't solved so even added middlePanel.repaint() after middlePanel.validate(). But that also didn't solve. The output is the same - got to move mouse around.

Comment: REG layout, the main reason am using Border (mainPanel) & middlePanel is Free layout is I want to resize components on change of screen size. The panel that am passing to middlePanel is GridLayout. CardLayout wont give me that facility. Any suggestions for that.

Comment: Tried revalidate() instead of validate(), but no success. Though the process was a bit faster but had to move cursor around.

Comment: @mre, camickr, I have 5 panels at this moment to replace on clicks - later that will be increased. Do you think adding so many panel instances to CardLayout is a good idea. Wont it unnecesarrily take memory and slow down the process.

Comment: *"Do you think adding so many panel instances to CardLayout is a good idea."* 5? **LOL!**  Try adding 5000 and see if it slows the JRE down.  Report back.

Comment: I tried implementing CardLayout & it works very well. No repaint/refresh problem.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `mainPanel.repaint()`