# NetBeans & Swing - dynamically add JPanel to JDialog

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel, jdialog

I am designing an application in NetBeans, as illustrated in the screenshot below.

[image]

When the user clicks on a JButton on a JFrame, a JDialog pops-up asking the user to enter a numeric value using a numeric keypad. I would like the JDialog to dynamically add 2 JPanels. JPanel 1 will contain a textbox for input. JPanel 2 will contain a numeric keypad. I designed them this way so that I could reuse the numeric keypad whenever I need it. The problem I am facing is displaying dynamically these 2 JPanels on the JDialog that pops-up. JDialog pops-up empty. Please take a look at my code below. Thank you all, I appreciate your help

**This is the sample code of JDialog:**

```
public class MyDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    public MyDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {//Add JPanel 2 (Numeric Keypad) to JDialog
                Container contentPane = getContentPane();
                NumericKeypadPanel nkp = new NumericKeypadPanel();
                nkp.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
                contentPane.removeAll();
                contentPane.add(nkp);
                contentPane.validate();
                contentPane.repaint();
            }
        });
    }
```

**This is the sample code for JPanel 2 (Numeric Keypad):**

```
public class NumericKeypadPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /** Creates new form NumericKeypadPanel */
    public NumericKeypadPanel() {
        initComponents();//Draws 10 number buttons
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basicall there are two ways

1) add a new `JComponent` by holding `JDialog` size (in pixels) on the screen, all JCompoenets
or part of them could be shrinked

2) resize `JDialog` by calling `pack()`, then `JDialog` will be resized

[both my a.m. rulles works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6989230/714968) by using [Standard LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) (excepting [AbsoluteLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html))

Answer (score 1):

What is in the initComponents() function of the NumericKeypadPanel?  If it's not actually creating components, you're not going to see anything in the dialog.  I added a single line to the NumericKeypadPanel's constructor to change the background color of this panel, and indeed, it shows up in the dialog as a green panel.

```
public NumericKeypadPanel() {
    //initComponents();//Draws 10 number buttons
    setBackground(Color.green);
}
```

Comment: initComponents() function is to draw numeric buttons. I accidentally figured out the solution for this. In NetBeans you can simply drag and drop a custom made JPanel to a JDialog or JFrame. The solution is so easy I never thought of it earlier. I need to play around more with NetBeans to discover all of the hidden features.