# Refreshing another view(JComboBox) on input new value

Tags: java, swing, oop, jcombobox

I have 2 views in my application in one of them (lets call it A) I can enter a value and add this to a List in the next view (lets call it B) when I launch this view everything is just fine when I add every item like this in my constructor

```
for (Rekening r : app.getRekeningen()) {
         rekeningList.addItem(r);
}
```

But when I add a new item in view A while view B is open it obviously doesn't update the JComboBox with the new value. My question is How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904639/how-to-refresh-the-jcombobox-data

Comment: Nope doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

- Create a reference to the listModel in B that you can update in A
- A method on B that you can call from A that will take the new value as a parameter.  Then add that item to the list model and possibly call `repaint()` on the view.

Comment: Thanks. I used the second for the input box in B but is it a best practice that views know each others presence? I assumed that it had to do anything with a kind of observable or anything.

Comment: It is not bad practice for A to know about B.  What becomes a problem is when A depends on B and B depends on A, that is called 'coupling'.