# How to control a combo box using another combo box?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

[image]

What I want is when I click subject combo box the `Batch Name:` combo box should change according to subject selection. I tried this but nothing happens. This code is in `Subject Name:` combo box action performed function.

```
private void combosubjActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
 String sub= evt.getSource().toString();
 try {
   btchcombo.removeAllItems();
   Connection conn = getConnection();
   PreparedStatement prpd = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT batch FROM BATCHLIST where subject=?");
   prpd.setString(1,sub);
   ResultSet rs = prpd.executeQuery();
   while (rs.next()) {
     String pat = rs.getString("BATCH");
     btchcombo.addItem(pat);
   }
   } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }    
 }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some data to replace the DB.

Comment: BTW - 1) `combosubjActionPerformed(` that looks suspicious. Have you checked this method is actually being called? 2) `{                                          
      ]  String sub= evt.getSource().toString();` That rubbish would not even compile. Don't waste your time, or more importantly **our** time, by posting a 'close facsimile' of the code used. Copy / paste an MCVE / SSCCE that you have confirmed shows the error.

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't that simple. Just calling `addItem()` is simply not sufficient to update the combo box data; and the UI representation of that thing.

You want to look into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904639/how-to-refresh-the-jcombobox-data) here for the required details to get that done.

But beyond that: you should really step back here and do some reading how to properly build a UI application that connects to a database. It is simply absolutely **wrong** for an ActionListener to directly pull data from the database!

First of all, this violates any ideas of **layering**. You put **abstractions** between your UI and the database. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217611/the-mvc-pattern-and-swing) or 
[there](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/model.html) for further reading.

Then: that `actionPerformed()` method is called by the so called **event dispatcher thread**. That thread is meant for **dispatching event**. You shouldn't "occupy it" for making calls down to the database. You know, what if you run out of DB connections; and that DB code ... sits there for a minute, waiting to get its turn? That will cause your UI to **freeze** because the thread responsible for keeping the UI going ... sits there and waits for your DB.

Long story short: it seems that you are over-burdening yourself. You should step back, and spent quite some time *learning* about such aspects. Otherwise, the result of your work will be buggy, and nobody will want to use it.