# Mouselistener and mouseclicked

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, mouselistener

I was just messing around with MouseListener and wanted to add a new JButton to my Panel whenever `buttP` is clicked; however, it doesn't refresh the Panel when I press `buttP`.
I tried the repaint method but that doesn't work. Anyone know how I can refresh the panel so that the new `JButton` shows automatically?

```
public class Panel extends JPanel{

private JButton buttP;
public Panel(){
    buttP = new JButton("TEST");
    buttP.addMouseListener(new addNewButtMouseListener());
    add(buttP);
}

private class addNewButtMouseListener implements MouseListener{

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        JButton b = new JButton("HA");
        add(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

}

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `invalidate()`, or `revalidate()`.

BTW don't use a `MouseListener` (+1 for @mKorbel) use `ActionListener` instead.

Comment: no, never ever, no reason to use `invalidate()`, sure could be important for `AWT`, `Swing`, up to Java1.4, see code example linked in my answer ...

Answer (score 1):

- I think idea to add [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) to the [`JButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) is wrong
- have to add [`SwingAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
- [code example and with required methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6989230/714968)