# How to properly use the MouseMotionListener to press JButtons?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, mousemotionlistener

I have made a small Conway Game of Life program. I'm about 80% done. I have used a grid of `JButtons` as the cells. Right now I have a `ButtonListener` on every button so you have to one-by-one draw the pattern you want by clicking on individual buttons. I want to be able to click and drag the mouse and select buttons quickly. I used the `MotionListener` class, implementing the `MouseMotionListener` and coded the `mouseDragged` method in an identical fashion as my `actionPerformed` method in my `ButtonListener` class.

I thought the logic should be the same but I'm definitely missing something. I played around with it a bit, thinking that it was just selecting and de-selecting over and over faster than I could tell. I added a check to make sure that it did not try and change the same button back-to-back but that did not help. Here is my `MotionListener` class:

```
    class MotionListener implements MouseMotionListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (e.getSource() == squares[i][j]) {
                    if (litSquares[i][j] == false) {
                        squares[i][j].setBackground(selected);
                        litSquares[i][j] = true;
                    } else {
                        squares[i][j].setBackground(backGround);
                        litSquares[i][j] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

My JButton array is `squares[][]` and the `litSquares[][]` is a boolean map of what is selected currently, that I use when calculating the next step.

Any ideas on how to correct my `MotionListener`? I'm not understanding something about how to properly implement this class. All simple examples I find deal with drawing, but they all seem to track the `Points` where the cursor is dragged and update the pixels afterward. Is that something I will have to do somehow with my buttons?

***** Here is the MCVE, or at least as small as I could condense it. *****

```
package extraCredit;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class MCVE extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8031881678612431401L;

    static JFrame frame;
    static JPanel grid;
    static JButton[][] squares;
    static boolean[][] litSquares, boardCopy;
    static int size, boardSize, tick = 1, goal = 100, rateIncrease = 10;
    ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
    MotionListener mListerner = new MotionListener();
    Border noBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
    Color backGround = Color.BLUE;
    Color selected = Color.PINK;

    public MCVE(int size) {
        MCVE.size = size;
        squares = new JButton[size][size];
        litSquares = new boolean[size][size];
        grid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(size, size));
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                squares[i][j] = new JButton();
                squares[i][j].addActionListener(listener);
                // squares[i][j].addMouseMotionListener(mListerner);
                squares[i][j].setBackground(backGround);
                squares[i][j].setBorder(noBorder);
                grid.add(squares[i][j]);
            }
        }

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(grid, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setTitle("Life");
        if (25 * size < 525) {
            boardSize = 525;
        } else {
            boardSize = 25 * size;
        }
        frame.setSize(boardSize, boardSize);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                    if (e.getSource() == squares[i][j]) {
                        if (litSquares[i][j] == false) {
                            squares[i][j].setBackground(selected);
                            litSquares[i][j] = true;
                        } else {
                            squares[i][j].setBackground(backGround);
                            litSquares[i][j] = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class MotionListener implements MouseMotionListener {

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                    if (e.getSource() == squares[i][j]) {
                        if (litSquares[i][j] == false) {
                            squares[i][j].setBackground(selected);
                            litSquares[i][j] = true;
                        } else {
                            squares[i][j].setBackground(backGround);
                            litSquares[i][j] = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new MCVE(20);
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION BELOW**, Thanks to @MadProgrammer and @durron597 . Mad answered my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422313/how-to-properly-use-the-mousemotionlistener-to-press-jbuttons) that was hanging me up on this problem.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ChangesAttempt extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8031881678612431401L;

static JFrame frame;
static JPanel grid;
static JLabel[][] squares;
static boolean[][] litSquares;
static int size, boardSize;
static boolean startDrag, origin;
static Set<Component> compList = new HashSet<Component>();
MouseEvent listener = new MouseEvent();
MotionListener mListerner = new MotionListener();
Color backGround = Color.BLUE;
Color selected = Color.PINK;

public ChangesAttempt(int size) {
    ChangesAttempt.size = size;
    squares = new JLabel[size][size];
    litSquares = new boolean[size][size];
    grid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(size, size));
    grid.addMouseMotionListener(mListerner);
    grid.addMouseListener(listener);
    setBoard();

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(grid, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setTitle("ChangedLife");
    if (25 * size < 525)
        boardSize = 525;
    else
        boardSize = 25 * size;
    frame.setSize(boardSize, boardSize);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

class MouseEvent implements MouseListener {

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
        startDrag = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
        Component source = e.getComponent().getComponentAt(e.getPoint());
        System.out.println("X = " +source.getX() + ", Y = " + source.getY());
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (source == squares[i][j]) {
                    if (litSquares[i][j] == false) {
                        squares[i][j].setBackground(selected);
                        litSquares[i][j] = true;
                    } else {
                        squares[i][j].setBackground(backGround);
                        litSquares[i][j] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
        compList.clear();
    }
}

class MotionListener implements MouseMotionListener {
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
        compList.add(e.getComponent().getComponentAt(e.getPoint()));
        updateBoard();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {

    }
}

public void setBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            squares[i][j] = new JLabel();
            squares[i][j].setOpaque(true);
            squares[i][j].setBackground(backGround);
            grid.add(squares[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

public void updateBoard(){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (compList.contains(squares[i][j])) {
                if(startDrag){
                    startDrag = false;
                    origin = litSquares[i][j];
                }
                if (litSquares[i][j] == origin) {
                    if(origin)
                        squares[i][j].setBackground(backGround);
                    else
                        squares[i][j].setBackground(selected);
                    litSquares[i][j] = !litSquares[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyLabel extends JLabel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1414933339546989142L;

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new ChangesAttempt(20);
}
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Just added the MCVE, condensed as much as I could.

Comment: _" I want to be able to click and drag the mouse and select buttons quickly."_ I don't get what is it exactly you are trying to drag? More precisely, I don't get what that statement means

Comment: I'm not sure about this. You can add mose listener to the JPanel and you can use public Component getComponentAt(int x, int y) to get component at a position. X,Y Position you'll get from MouseEvent. Try this I hope it'll work. If it works please update me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524029/mouselistener-and-mouseclicked

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I will report what I get to work. @peeskillet I mean I would like to "paint" the buttons basically when I hold the left mouse button and drag, so if I click on selected button it deselects it and any other selected buttons I drag over, vice versa for un-selected buttons.

Comment: @peeskillet , You were right about using Component. I posted the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you're having is that you're trying to use `JButton` for something it's not designed to do. I would go with a much simpler control, like `JLabel`, so that you won't have all the extra functionality that `JButton` has.

Secondly, your `litSquares` array is clearly a [Data Clump](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/data-clumps). You absolutely should be creating your own custom control (which can either `extend JComponent` or `extend JLabel`), depending on whether `JLabel` meets your needs, that contains the other information that should be paired with the control itself.

Thirdly, you might not want the state of the button to be a `boolean`, you probably want it to be an `enum`... like

```
public enum State {
    UNLIT, LIT, CURRENTLY_SELECTED;
}
```

so that you can see which components are being newly color-flipped.

Finally, as was mentioned in the comments, use `public Component getComponentAt(int x, int y)` to be able to figure out what the `MouseMotionListener` was dragged over, and use that to change the color.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I have switched over to `JLabels`. Currently I don't know how to get the `JPanel` `MotionListener` to see the mouse, since it is covered by my `JLabels` and they block it. If I add the `MotionListener` the the `JLabels` themselves, the Point returned is relative to that specific `JLabel`

Comment: I haven't yet got rid of the boolean arrays like you said but it is functioning. I will continue working on it to get the `JLabel` extended to incorporate the `enum`.