# How to manage several panels in the same jframe?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I'm developing a game as college work, I've a fully autonomus panel that handles all process of the game, but I want to add a menu that allows to select the differents levels and difficulties, and there's the problem.
I only have one frame, so I've to manage two panels in this. How can I change the panels? I've read something about CardLayout, but I don't know if it's that I need really.
I'm doing tests adding and removing the panels , but It doesn't work fine. How can I do it?

**Edit** I think that the problem is the previous panel is not removed, so the add/remove way doesn't work.

Comment: *"fully autonomus panel"*  What is a 'fully autonomus panel'?  It sounds like this is shoving application logic into a place it is not supposed to be (and doing it sideways).

Comment: Your question is tough to answer without some idea of the type of layout you're looking for.  Take a look at this Swing tutorial page, and imagine that the JButtons are JPanels.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `CardLayout`, but I don't know if it's that I need really. ..

Yes, it is.

> I'm doing tests adding and removing the panels , but It doesn't work
>   fine.

[please is there some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6989230/714968), for why [reason to simulate CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)