# How to force JContainer to re-layout itself?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtextarea, jdialog

I have `JFrame` with `BorderLayout`: `JTextArea` in the `NORTH` and `JButton` in the `SOUTH`. I `pack()` it in the beginning.

My code changes **font size** for the text area. How do I force the dialog window and its components to re-layout itself?

So far I tried some combinations of:

- another `pack()`
- `repaint()`
- `revalidate()`

It does not seem to help.

Is there a guaranteed brute force approach?  What is the proper way to achieve such result?

**UPDATE:**

While creating SCCE (see below) I found two mistakes in my original code and fixed them. **The frame is re-sizing nicely now.**

I still have a question whether this is the **proper** way to do it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private JTextArea txt;
    private JButton bis;
    private JFrame frame;

    int size = 10;

    private void BuildMainGUI() {
        txt = new JTextArea("This is just a line of text");
        bis = new JButton("Increase size");

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        bis.addActionListener(this);

        BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();

        p1.setLayout(bl);
        p1.add(txt, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p1.add(bis, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(p1);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        size += 2;
        Font newFont = new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, size);
        txt.setFont(newFont);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.pack();
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyFrame myGUI = new MyFrame(); 
        myGUI.BuildMainGUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is correct suggestion, but there are three proper ways, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about your view

Comment: @mKorbel - OK. I will try to keep it short.

Comment: @mKorbel - As many times in my long programming career, all it took to find the problem was to get rid of unrelated code and concentrate on what's left.

Comment: `While creating SCCE (see below) I found two mistakes in my original code and fixed them` - and that is why a SSCCE should be provided with every question. Most of the time creating the SSCCE solves the problem so you don't even need to ask it.

Comment: very good SSCCE, my hat down (missing there Initial Thread, but doesn't matter)

Comment: _"I still have a question whether this is the proper way to do it."_ You usually should not be extending JFrame (extend JPanel instead). Also, you should initialize your gui with the `EventQueue`. Also, what is the use of your MyFrame? You're not even using it(it is a JFrame)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all three alternativer are described in ActionListener, lets work easiest of them, seems like is coordinates is the same (I think that required deepest look into TextLayout ???)

[image] [image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ResizeJTextArea {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 15);
    private JButton button = new JButton("change");
    private Font newFont = new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 10);

    public ResizeJTextArea() {
        textArea.setText("This is just a line of text");
        textArea.setFont(newFont);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                textArea.setFont(textArea.getFont().deriveFont(20f));

                //2. choice
                //textArea.setColumns(20);
                //textArea.setRows(20);

                //3rd. coice
                //override PreferredScrollableViewportSize
                frame.pack();
            }
        });
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ResizeJTextArea fs = new ResizeJTextArea();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you saying that `pack()` **alone** is all what it takes in my case?

Comment: [(re)validate & repaint is about add, remove, modify JComponents in Container see all possible variations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6989230/714968), result from this code is are you want to resize JFrame (mentioned JDialog) or not, have to decide :-)

Comment: RE: "*JFrame (mentioned JDialog)*"  Well, one of the two stupid mistakes in my original code was that I was actually re-sizing a **wrong container**: Dialog (separate window) instead of Frame.