# Remove last row from JPanel set with GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, grid-layout

I have a `JPanel` which has `GridLayout` as the layout. I have a plus button at the end of the Main Panel to add some panels to the grid. I need a minus button that subsequently removes the last row added to the grid.

I saw the docs related and it shows `removeAll()` method, which is not useful for me as I need to remove only the last row.

Also it shows some `remove(int index)`. Again I am unaware of the index of the last row, though I tried doing this:

```
myPanel.remove(0);
```

but this removes the first row.

Comment: Is this a single column grid layout?  Consider using a `JList` instead (either way).

Comment: [parentPanel.getComponentCount() - 1???, to adapt this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6989230/714968)

Comment: yes its a single column grid as i am basically adding an entire mini panel on click of plus button

Comment: int count = panel.getComponentCount(); panel.remove(count-1); Did the trick,Thanks mKorbel

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the component at index x:

```
myPanel.remove(x);
```

If you want to add a component instead of the one you've removed:

```
myPanel.add(component c , x);
```

Then you should repaint:

```
myPanel.validate();
myPanel.repaint();
```

Comment: okey i am sorry :
myPanel.remove(x);  //where x is the index of the component you want to remove
myPanel.add(component c , x);   //if you want to add a component instead of the one you've removed
myPanel.validate(); 
myPanel.repaint();