# dynamically adding JButton to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jpanel, jbutton

I have three panels inside one panel(which is inside JFrame).In the middle panel there are some 30 JButtons.Now I want to add JButton dynamically inside the middle panel on click of a leftmost panel JButton.I am doing following

```
imagePanel.add(newBtn);
imagePanel.revalidate();
outermostPanel.revalidate();
```

But,on doing this nothing happens.I don't want to use repaint as I will re-draw the complete middle panel and I am only left the new JButton,the previously added 30 JButtons are gone.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) for tips on adding components dynamically.  Clicking the `Add Another Label` button will add labels on demand.

Comment: Has imagePanel been added to the component tree?

Comment: [basics stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6989230/714968)

Comment: @David Horvath-imagePanel is inside a JScrollPane

Comment: It worked after setting 

    setButtonBounds(oldbeacons);
    imagePanel.add(newBtn);  
    imagePanel.revalidate();
    imagePanel.repaint();
But,why do we need to re-draw the previously created components?

Comment: Because the position of the components may be adjusted by the layout manager after the component has been added. For example if you are using a FlowLayout and the components are "centered" on the panel, adding one more component will cause all components to shift.