# JDialog components won't show up

Tags: java, jdialog

So I have the following code.

```
public class GraveyardFrame extends JDialog{

private List<JLabel> labelList = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Piece> pieces = new ArrayList<>();

public GraveyardFrame(final Player player) {
    setSize(300,300);
    setTitle("Graveyard Zone~ Watch out!!");
    setResizable(false);
    setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);  
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);    
    setVisible(true);
    createView(player);   //here I add all the components
}

public void createView(Player player) {
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    add(mainPanel);
    mainPanel.setBackground(new Color(128,64,0));
    createLabels(player ,mainPanel);   //here I add the labels, that will take the icon of the dead pieces
    this.pack();
}

private void createLabels(Player player , JPanel mainPanel) {
    pieces.addAll(player.getPlayerGraveyard());   //pieces holds all the dead pieces
    int sizeOfgraveyard = player.getPlayerGraveyard().size();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < sizeOfgraveyard ; i++) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setSize(60, 60);         
        label.setIcon(pieces.get(i).getIcon());
        labelList.add(label);
        mainPanel.add(label); 
        mainPanel.validate();
        mainPanel.repaint();
    }
}
```

It is supposed to pop up a JDialog that takes all the dead pieces of a chess player and display them.
First I used a JFrame , but I find out that a JFrame can't wait for an action to happen and only then continue with the main GUI .(in JDialog , using ModalityType is enough ).

The problem is that it doesn`t show anything, just an empty JDialog box. I searched for this problem, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988317/dynamically-add-components-to-a-jdialog) somebody said that you should use validate() ,repaint() and pack() . I tried this, as in the code above, but still nothing happens

This is how it should look like (works with JFrame instead of JDialog) :[image: fine]
This is how it actually looks like (with the code above) : [image: not fine]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `setVisible(true)` before `createView()`. But as it is a `JDialog` which is modal, calling `setVisible()` actually blocks until the dialog is dismissed. So, `createView()` will only be called once the dialog got closed.

Just change the order of the two method calls, first `createView()` and next `setVisible(true)`, and it should work.